# Succes message with image. Contact form 7

Tags: html, wordpress, image

Im using the Contact Form 7 WordPress plugin and everything is fine, but one thing won't work at all..

I want to add an image and iframe too the succes message. So i just added this to my succes message field:

```
<img src="someimg.png">
```

But that doesnt work, you just see this code coming up, not as an image but just like real text. 
So then i tried to use this, because CF7 places the text between " ".

```
"<img src="someimg.png">"
```

But also with no succes, someone who can help me out?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/submission.php` you should see the beginning of the success `elseif` statement on line 144. You should be able to override the response on line 146.

You would want something like this:

```
$this->response = '<img scr="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Testing" />';
```

Comment: I replaced rule #157 to this:
$this->response = 'Wij nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op!<img src="">'; But still i see the tags and not the img

Comment: Check the example I added.

Comment: i get a blank page on submit now :/

Comment: Sorry, I should not have had echo in that example. Anything between the single quotes should output in the success `<div>`. Let me know if it worked for you. It works on my end.

Comment: It does output it in the DIV, but you actually see the code and not the image, you understand what i mean?

Comment: That's interesting. What version of Contact Form 7 are you using? I was able to output an image using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried some things, and i saw that an IMG element gets changed to this.

```
&lt;img scr="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Testing" /&gt;
```

So i think thats the problem, but someone who knows why this is happening?